# access session data inside ouput class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to access codeigniter session data i.e `$this->session->userdata('session_id');`

inside ouput class i.e `secure_system_folder/core/Output.php`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$CI =& get_instance;
$sess_id = $CI->session->userdata('session_id');
```

But what you're probably looking for is [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), they're a much easier way to extend the core without directly editing (and therefore possibly breaking) core files.